Looking for a Way to Put in Multiple Conditional Statements in an If/Then Statement in R
In R, I created a new variable called wbao such that all values if this variable are NA:
l_raw_2$wbao <- NA

However, I want to convert these NAs to different categorical values (0-3) given certain conditionals with another variable. For example, if ba109___e is 1 and ba109___a is 0, then I would want wbao to be 0, not NA. I wrote the following code:
if l_raw_2$ba109___e=1 && ba109___a=="0"
{wbao=0}

but ran into the following error:
Error: unexpected symbol in "if ba109___e"

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Any input regarding this would be much appreciated; thanks so much!

Try l_raw_2$wbao = ifelse(l_raw_2$ba109___e==1 & l_raw_2$ba109___a=="0", 0, l_raw_2$wbao)

Are ba109___e and ba109___a columns in l_raw_2?

Yep @JonSpring, ba109__e and ba109__a are both columns in l_raw_2.

Use nested ifelse statements, or dplyr::case_when.

Updated to address the concern in your response which I had misinterpreted.
library(dplyr)

l_raw_2 <- l_raw_2 %>%
  mutate(wbao = ifelse(
    `ba109__e` == 1 & `ba109__a` == 0,
    0,
    ifelse(
      <second conditional>,
      1,
      ifelse(
        <third conditional>,
        2,
        3,
      )
    )
  )
)

or
l_raw_2$wboa <- NA
l_raw_2$wbao <- ifelse(l_raw_2$ba109__e == 1 & l_raw_2$ba109__a == 0, 0, l_2_raw$wbao)
l_raw_2$wbao <- ifelse(<second conditional>, 1, l_raw_2$wbao)
... 

or
library(dplyr)

l_raw_2 <- l_raw_2 %>%
  mutate(
    wbao = case_when(
      `ba109__e` == 1 & `ba109__a` == 0 ~ 0,
      <second conditional> ~ <desired output>,
      ...
    )
  )


Thanks @Barry D! Wouldn't that overwrite some values depending on the logic?

Overwriting values can happen when categorising numeric ranges if the conditionals are not in the correct order. I don't think this will happen based on your minimal example.
Post the 4 conditionals you need to generate 0,1,2,3 for the column wbao and I'll respond in the morning if you haven't solved it yourself by then.

Thanks @Barry D, this actually helped.
